# Improving Chrome CPU cycle consumption

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

[image: Image showing heavy CPU usage]

I have a web page that uses three ng-repeats to render data coming from the server. Three services return a promise each and when resolved, the data returned from each service is rendered by a ng-repeated list. However because of that, as you can see in the attached screenshot, the yellows (the scripting time) is huge and takes up a lot of cpu time and memory. Because of this, other light-heavy applications open in other tabs slow down or sometimes become unresponsive. Any ideas as to how I can improve upon the performance here ?

Comment: What is the volume of data you are trying to render?

Comment: Not a lot. Say around 100 objects per service

Comment: This was a problem due to nested ng-ifs and nested ng-repeats that caused this to turn into a browser bomb of sorts